# Why Am I Getting a 1090 Error, an XML Parser Error?

Tags: xml, apache-flex

In my Flex 3 site, I'm getting a 1090 error, an xml parser error in IE only. It works in Safari and Firefox. Does anyone see a problem with this xml?

```
<adXMLReturn>
  <script type="text/javascript"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/ajs.php?zoneid=4&amp;cb=82622824804&amp;charset=UTF-8&amp;loc=http%3A//localhost/property-debug/property.html%3Fdebug%3Dtrue"/>
  <a href="http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=1__zoneid=4__cb=3ab5c92ee5__oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dcscore.com" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/ai.php?filename=mybanner.png&amp;contenttype=png" alt="" title="" border="0" height="60" width="468"/>
  </a>
  <div id="beacon_3ab5c92ee5" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: hidden;">
    <img src="http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&amp;campaignid=1&amp;zoneid=4&amp;loc=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fproperty-debug%2Fproperty.html%3Fdebug%3Dtrue&amp;cb=3ab5c92ee5" alt="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;" height="0" width="0"/>
  </div>
  <noscript>
    <a href="http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?n=a0ea89cb&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://www.dcscore.com/openx/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=4&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=a0ea89cb" border="0" alt=""/>
    </a>
  </noscript>
</adXMLReturn>
```

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: What does this question have to do with flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone. Actually, this XML validates. I had a problem in another variable.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0):

```
Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.
```

Look at your XML tag, there is something wrong which is causing this problem. The problem is that your XML is not perfect and has mistakes.